# mongodb why do we need getSisterDB

Tags: mongodb

While playing with mognodb console help, I found a `db.getSisterDB()` method.

And I am curious what is the purpose of this method. Looking through mongodb documentation and  a quick google search did not yield satisfactory results.

By typing db.getSisterDb.help generates an error and typing `db.getSisterDB` gives the following definition of this method:

```
function ( name ){
    return this.getMongo().getDB( name );
}
```

which suggests that this is just a wrapper around `getDB`. My suggestion that it is used in to access databases in a replica set, but I would like to listen to a person who can give me a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the shell, `db` is a reference to the current database.  If you want to query against a different DB in the same `mongod` instance, the way to get a proper reference to it would be to use this method (which has an alias, more gender neutral getSiblingDB).

If you wanted to use the longer syntax, you could: `db.getMongo().getDB(name)` gets you the same thing as `db.getSiblingDB(name)` or `db.getSisterDB(name)` but the former is longer to type.

All of the above work the same way in standalone `mongod` as well as replica sets (and sharded clusters).

Answer (score 3):

Im going to add to the accepted answer because I did not find what I wanted as a first result.

`getSiblingDB` exists for scripting, where the `use` helper is not available

`getSiblingDB` is the newer between the identical `getSisterDB`, so use sibling as `getSisterDB` is no longer in documentation

when used in the shell, `getSiblingDB` serves the purpose of getting a database without changing the db variable